# Weka DBSCAN set epsilon based on geographic data

Tags: gps, cluster-analysis, weka, dbscan

I have a set of geographic data with the format:

```
46.52100798 6.567126449  gps
46.52368591 6.59208188   gps
46.52338534 6.593065244  gps
46.52303304 6.594046262  gps
```

I want to do DBSCAN clustering and set the epsilon parameter which identical to real distance like 5 meters:
Currently code as following:

```
public static float distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);
    return dist;
}
```

// a method for calculating the distance given two pair of geographic data.

```
    cl  = new DBSCAN();
    double [] timeArray = new double[data.numInstances()-1];

    for (int i = 1; i<data.numInstances();i++){
        timeArray[i-1] =(data.instance(i).value(0)-data.instance(i-1).value(0));
    }
    Arrays.sort(timeArray);
    int point =(int)(30*60/timeArray[data.numInstances()/2]);
    System.out.println(point);
    cl.setMinPoints(point);
    cl.setEpsilon(0.01);
    cl.buildClusterer(newData);
```

// set the parameters for DBSCAN instance
anyone knows how to plug the above piece of distance calculating code to the DBSCAN instance?

Comment: ELKI is much more extensible - and already contains this distance function. It also seems to be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

ELKI already includes this distance function, `LatLngDistanceFunction` (beware that the order of latitude and longitude matters; which is why we provide both depending on your column order).

```
-algorithm.distancefunction geo.LatLngDistanceFunction
```

Distances using this distance function will be in *meters*. With the parameter `-geo.model` you can also switch between different Earth approximations such as simple spherical models, or the WGS84 spheroid. For DBSCAN this does not make a big difference, because you will want to use a small epsilon (such as the 5 meters you suggested) anyway.

ELKI also includes *indexing* capabilities for this distance function. When you have large data sets, ELKI will be *much* faster (and I invite you to *benchmark* Weka against ELKI yourself). Details on **index acceleration for geo distance** can be found in the publication:

> E. Schubert, A. Zimek, H.-P. Kriegel
>   **[Geodetic Distance Queries on R-Trees for Indexing Geographic Data](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-40235-7_9)**
>   In Proceedings of the 13th International Symposium on Spatial and Temporal Databases (SSTD), Munich, Germany: 146–164, 2013.

As long as you choose epsilon small enough and use real-world data, a R*-tree will usually give you a speedup from O(n^2) to approx. O(n log n) - if you have millions of points, the speedup often is 100x-1000x.